# google maps static Map: Implicit Positioning of the Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

> Normally, you need to specify center and zoom URL parameters to define
>   the location and zoom level of your generated map. However, if you
>   supply markers, path, or visible parameters, you can instead let the
>   Static Maps API determine the correct center and zoom level
>   implicitly, based on evaluation of the position of these elements.
>
> If supplying two or more elements, the Static Maps API will determine
>   a proper center and zoom level, providing generous margins for the
>   elements contained.

[**source**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#ImplicitPositioning)
As you can see from the pics below in my case I supply  markers and path and visible but no matter what there is more availible space to do more zoom sometimes.

with visible parameter
[image: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=330x230&markers=size:tiny|color:green|(31.80501,%2035.233979999999974)&markers=size:tiny|color:red|(31.80452,%2035.23406)&visible=(31.80501,%2035.233979999999974),(31.80452,%2035.23406)&path=color:0x0000ff|weight:3|(31.805010000000003,%2035.23398)|(31.80487,%2035.23378)|(31.804790000000004,%2035.233740000000004)|(31.804740000000002,%2035.233740000000004)|(31.804690000000004,%2035.233760000000004)|(31.804630000000003,%2035.2338)|(31.804570000000002,%2035.233920000000005)|(31.804520000000004,%2035.23406)&sensor=false]

[url](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=330x230&markers=size:tiny|color:green|(31.80501,%2035.233979999999974)&markers=size:tiny|color:red|(31.80452,%2035.23406)&visible=(31.80501,%2035.233979999999974),(31.80452,%2035.23406)&path=color:0x0000ff|weight:3|(31.805010000000003,%2035.23398)|(31.80487,%2035.23378)|(31.804790000000004,%2035.233740000000004)|(31.804740000000002,%2035.233740000000004)|(31.804690000000004,%2035.233760000000004)|(31.804630000000003,%2035.2338)|(31.804570000000002,%2035.233920000000005)|(31.804520000000004,%2035.23406)&sensor=false)

without visible parameter
[image: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=330x230&markers=size:tiny|color:green|(31.80501,35.233979999999974)&markers=size:tiny|color:red|(31.80452,35.23406)&path=color:0x0000ff|weight:3|(31.805010000000003,35.23398)|(31.804520000000004,35.23406)&sensor=false]

[url](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=330x230&markers=size:tiny|color:green|(31.80501,35.233979999999974)&markers=size:tiny|color:red|(31.80452,35.23406)&path=color:0x0000ff|weight:3|(31.805010000000003,35.23398)|(31.804520000000004,35.23406)&sensor=false)

[image]

**Question:**
how to make static map links change zoom/bound automaticly better then this?

Unwanted symbols detected it was my fault. Now working great! **SOLVED**

BUT in some cases when step's parameters line is too long like this
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=350x200&markers=size:mid|color:green|label:A|31.5997,34.81200999999999&markers=size:mid|color:red|label:B|31.50691,34.78232000000003&path=color:red|weight:2|31.599700000000002,34.81201|31.599500000000003,34.81197|31.599480000000003,34.811960000000006|31.599180000000004,34.81188|31.59916,34.811870000000006|31.598950000000002,34.81188|31.598720000000004,34.81192|31.5984,34.81199|31.597780000000004,34.81213|31.59737,34.812200000000004|31.597030000000004,34.812250000000006|31.596850000000003,34.81226|31.59645,34.81228|31.596040000000002,34.812250000000006|31.595530000000004,34.81217|31.594900000000003,34.812000000000005|31.59401,34.81172|31.593590000000003,34.81156|31.593180000000004,34.811370000000004|31.592090000000002,34.810880000000004|31.591140000000003,34.81045|31.59063,34.810230000000004|31.590000000000003,34.809960000000004|31.589340000000004,34.809670000000004|31.588910000000002,34.80948|31.588500000000003,34.80932|31.58799,34.80914|31.587540000000004,34.809000000000005|31.58706,34.80886|31.586570000000002,34.80872|31.58603,34.808580000000006|31.585510000000003,34.80847|31.584020000000002,34.808170000000004|31.582850000000004,34.807930000000006|31.5816,34.807680000000005|31.580940000000002,34.807550000000006|31.579900000000002,34.80736|31.5786,34.80709|31.57766,34.80691|31.576020000000003,34.80657|31.574960000000004,34.806360000000005|31.574270000000002,34.80622|31.573680000000003,34.806110000000004|31.573230000000002,34.806020000000004|31.573050000000002,34.80599|31.572810000000004,34.80594|31.571640000000002,34.8057|31.570470000000004,34.80547|31.570100000000004,34.80539|31.569450000000003,34.80525|31.569180000000003,34.80519|31.568270000000002,34.80498|31.5679,34.804880000000004|31.56745,34.804770000000005|31.56642,34.80451|31.56134,34.80308|31.558040000000002,34.80214|31.547030000000003,34.798930000000006|31.544200000000004,34.798120000000004|31.542270000000002,34.797470000000004|31.53995,34.79666|31.53796,34.795820000000006|31.535420000000002,34.794630000000005|31.53393,34.7939|31.532210000000003,34.79296|31.53065,34.79205|31.52821,34.79045|31.528080000000003,34.79036|31.527770000000004,34.79014|31.526820000000004,34.78947|31.525610000000004,34.788610000000006|31.52473,34.78793|31.52174,34.78553|31.520290000000003,34.784490000000005|31.51929,34.783840000000005|31.518020000000003,34.7832|31.516750000000002,34.78269|31.515560000000004,34.78229|31.51554,34.78228|31.514640000000004,34.78208|31.51443,34.78204|31.51338,34.78188|31.513050000000003,34.781850000000006|31.512190000000004,34.78177|31.511350000000004,34.78175|31.51039,34.78183|31.50953,34.78192|31.5086,34.78204|31.50691,34.782320000000006&sensor=false

any suggesstions?

Comment: Not enough data. How are you generating those images (what is the URL you are providing?) An error in the URL can often give this sort of result.

Comment: @qpaycm no urls is not ok. i see url like http://i.stack.imgur.com/V151n.png

Comment: checked when posted it's worked. sorry. 2 new links in topic ▲

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove unnecessary characters from your url. 
try this http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=330x230&markers=size:tiny|color:green|31.80501,35.233979999999974&markers=size:tiny|color:red|31.80452,35.23406&visible=31.80501,35.233979999999974,31.80452,35.23406&path=color:0x0000ff|weight:3|31.805010000000003,35.23398|31.80487,35.23378|31.804790000000004,35.233740000000004|31.804740000000002,35.233740000000004|31.804690000000004,35.233760000000004|31.804630000000003,35.2338|31.804570000000002,35.233920000000005|31.804520000000004,35.23406&sensor=false

[image]

Comment: ok. one more question: some of steps can't load on image. looks like it happens because of GET length(too much points). any sugesstions?

Comment: probably you reach limits for free users, if so you can register business services https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Limits https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing